# Installed Ubuntu 16.04 but not actually installed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

Ok, so my problem is: I  made  2 partitions for Ubuntu 40 GB for /root and 4 GB for swap, I installed Ubuntu on the partitions successfully. It took 15 minutes but when I am opening my PC I have no dual boot option. I went into Disk Management and checked the 2 partitions. AND THEY WERE EMPTY. WHAT ? I installed you. Ok, I was freaking out tried to install again on 2 different partitions. SAME THING ... Is there a thing that I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Use a live CD to **try Ubuntu without installing** and when your system boot into it, install Boot-repair.

Open Terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
Then type the codes below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

After installation boot-repair will open. Then click the **"recommended repair"** button. Follow the instructions.

After completion, reboot your PC and check if you recovered access to your OSs.